# `req.session.user` is `undefined` when using `axios` and `express session`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to use express session with react/express frontend and backend. For the express server, I saved the user information in express session in success callback, then I set the credential in the express option and cors to true. However, when I use axios post request from the React frontend with `withCredential` set to true, `req.session.user` still shows up as undefined. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I tried to use middleware, but they were not helpful.

In `server.mjs`

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import User from './db.mjs';
import path from 'path';
import url from 'url';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import router from './routes/user.routes.mjs';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 600000,
        secure: true
      },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}))
app.use(
    cors({
      allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"], // you can change the headers
      exposedHeaders: ["authorization", 'set-cookie'], // you can change the headers
      origin: "*",
      credentials: true,
      origin: true,
      methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
      preflightContinue: false
    })
  );
  app.options({
    origin: true,
  credentials: true,
  })
  app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
  app.use('/api', router)
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
  }));
  // make {{user}} variable available for all paths
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user = req.session.user;
    next();
  });
  
  // logging
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.method, req.path, req.body);
    next();
  });


const login = (email, password, successCallback, errorCallback) => {
    // TODO: implement login

    const user = User.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {
        console.log(err,user)
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            errorCallback('USER SEARCH FAILED')
          }
          else {
            if (user === null) {
              errorCallback('USER NOT FOUND');
            }
            else {
              bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, passwordMatch) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  errorCallback("PASSWORD CHECK FAILED")
                }
                else {
                  if (passwordMatch) {
                    successCallback(user);
                  }
                  else {
                    errorCallback("PASSWORDS DO NOT MATCH");
                  }
                }
                
              });
            }
          }
    });


};




const startAuthenticatedSession = (req, user, cb) => {
    // TODO: implement startAuthenticatedSession
        console.log('starting new authenticated session', user);
        req.session.regenerate(function(err) {
            if (!err) {
            // set a property on req.session that represents the user
                req.session.user = user;
                cb(err);

            } else {
            // call callback with error
                cb(err);
            }
        })
    };

const endAuthenticatedSession = (req, cb) => {
// TODO: implement endAuthenticatedSession
    req.session.destroy((err) => { cb(err); });
};

const signup = (email, password, errorCallback, successCallback) => {
    // TODO: implement register
    if (password.length < 8) {
      errorCallback('PASSWORD TOO SHORT');
    }
    User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (result === null) {
        const hash = bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, hash) {
          // do more stuff here!
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              errorCallback({message: 'PASSWORD HASH FAILED'})
            }
            const newUser = new User({
              email: email,
              password: hash 
            });
            newUser.save(function(err, user, count) {
              if (err) {
                errorCallback('DOCUMENT SAVE ERROR')
              }
              successCallback(user);
              console.log(req.session.user);
            });
        });
        
      }
      else {
        errorCallback('EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS');
      }
    })
    User.findOne({'email': email});
  };




app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({"user": ["userOne", "userTwo", "userThree"]})
})

app.post("/api/login/", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    console.log(req.body)// assumes that User was registered in `./db.mjs`

    function success(newUser) {
        startAuthenticatedSession(req, newUser, (err) => {
            if (!err) {
                req.session.user = newUser;
                res.send({key:'success'});
            } else {
                res.render('error', {message: 'err authing???'}); 
            }
        });
    }

    login(email, password, success, (e)=>console.log(e));
})
```

In react frontend component

```
import '../../App.css';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import icon from '../../img/upload.svg';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

function handleFile(files) {
    alert("Number of files: " + files.length);
    console.log(files);
    const profileImg = 'profileImg';
    console.log(files[0].name);
    const formData = new FormData();
        
        formData.append(profileImg, files[0]);
        axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/user-profile", formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            withCredentials: true
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });

  }
```

console.log for undefined in post request

```
router.post('/user-profile', upload.single('profileImg'), (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.session.user);
```

Edit: the console log for `req.session`:

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2022-12-05T04:56:43.020Z,
    originalMaxAge: 600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
  }
}
```

[image: console.log]

Comment: What is the result of `req.session`?

Comment: I just edited the post to include it! It's defined but missing the field for user.